# Background class in Image Segmentation

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm training a U-Net model to segment 2 relevant objects from an image.
Thus, the U-Net's output are 2 predicted masks, one for each object.
However I've seen some posts that advice to include the background as a class as well.
Why is this needed? Since `B = I - (O1 union O2)` where `I, B, O1, O2` are set of pixels in the background, the entire image and the objects. What's the need to predict the background separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model only outputs 2 masks, it predicts for each pixel the probability of it to belong to `O1` **or** to `O2` - but it **cannot** predict "does not belong to any of them". Therefore, by definition, `O1 union O2 = I` - no room for background pixels.

To allow the model to predict "not belonging to `O1` or `O2`" you need to predict a third mask, which is the background mask.